American English: intervocalic rhotic lost after an alveolar flap/tap
Is there a phonological process by which a word such as federal is informally pronounced bisyllabically as /ˈfɛɾəl/?

A process? It's just how some people speak.

Hearing two syllables does not mean we say two. We say three very fast. And the central schwa is barely a syllable to begin with.

Do you mean /ˈfɛɾɹ̩l/? I don't think most speakers drop the /ɹ/ altogether; it doesn't sound like fettle.

@YosefBaskin I absolutely only say two syllables, and I think this is fairly common, but there's still an /ɹ/ there.

@YosefBaskin I wonder if it is a similar process to the two-syllable pronunciation of "natural"

Merriam-Webster lists the second/middle syllable as optional: "fe-d(ə-)rəl" in their representation.
